# Innodb, clustered indexes, and slow_query_log - hurt by the primary key?

Tags: mysql, innodb, clustered-index, full-table-scan

In the last few months we've migrated a few tables from MYiSAM to InnoDB. We did this, in theory, for the row locking advantage, since we are updating individual rows, through multiple web-scraping instances. I now have tens of thousands of slow_queries building up in my slow_query_log (10s). and a lot of full table scans. I am having event very simple updates to one row (updating 4 or 5 columns) take 28 seconds. (our i/o and efficiencies are very good, and failed/aborted attempts are very low < 0.5%)

The two tables we update the most have ID (int 11) as the primary key. In InnoDB the primary key is a clustered key, so are written to disk indexed in the order of ID. BUT our two most important record identifying columns are `BillsofLading` and `Container` (both varchar22). Most of our DML queries look up records based on these two columns. We also have indexes on `BillsofLading` and `container.`
The way I understand it, InnoDB also uses the primary key when creating these two secondary indexes.

So, I could have a record with `ID`=1, and `BillsofLading`='z', and another record `ID`=9 and `BillsofLading`='a'. With InnoDB indexes, when updating record based on a SELECT where `BillsofLading`='a', would I not still have to do a full scan to find 'a' since the index is based on the `ID`?

Thanks in advance for helping with the logic here!

Comment: The first thing to do is to run EXPLAIN to find out what the query execution plan is and where the resources are being consumed. Use a GI like Mysql Workbench or Toad to run the explain as they present the results much better.

Comment: @DavidSoussan I haven't had any obvious indicators from the EXPLAIN extended. Wondering if it is more an indicator of the application processing, and less so the actual DML statements.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE -- there might be obvious things.

Answer (score 1):

No, your example should not require a full scan, assuming that MySQL is choosing to use your `BillsofLading` index.  You say

> The way I understand it, InnoDB also uses the primary key when creating these two secondary indexes.

This is correct, but it does not mean what you think it means.

A primary key (PK) to InnoDB is like a line number to a human being.  It's InnoDB's only way to uniquely identify a row.  So what a secondary index does is map each value of the target column(s) to all the PKs (i.e. line numbers) that match that value.  Thus, MySQL can quickly jump to just the `BillsofLading` you care about, and then scan just those rows (PKs) for the one you want.

Comment: Ahh, so it finds the `BillsofLading` based on the billoflading index, then uses the primary key (line number) to go to that line for the rest of the columns? Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Sure.  To solve your overall query efficiency problems I would recommend starting with the worst offender in the slow query log (or perhaps the worst offender that is also a relatively simple query) and investigating why in particular that query is having problems.  This may shed light on why all the other queries are having problems too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you severely decrease key_buffer_size and set innodb_buffer_pool_size to about 70% of available RAM?

There are a number of subtle differences between MyISAM and InnoDB.  There are too many to list in this answer, and nothing you have said brings to mind any particular issue.  I suggest you review [Converting MyISAM to InnoDB](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb) to see what might be causing trouble.

Comment: Good questions. I am looking into these. I know the i/o values look pretty good.